# Buttons and Labels cames over the Menu's JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, menu, jbutton

I really hope you can help me with this problem.
I have been working in a NetBeans app, and I created an animated slide menu using a JPanel, so I was intending to make the user shows up the menu that slides and covers part of the content of the current panel in the app, the user interacts with menu (it presses one of the buttons on the menu) and menu slides left to be hidden again.

Photos of the menu Hidden and Shown:
[image]
[image]

My issue here, is if among the content covered by the menu (when the menu is released) there is a jButton or a jLabel, these just overlay the content of the menu, they keep visible, and they came in front covering the menu's content.

[image]

Issues here:

[image: As you can see the content comes over the content of the menu]

I have tried fixing it by making some button and labels *hidden* when the menu shows up, using the method `ButtonOrLabel.setVisible(false)` and once the user presses the button that hides the menu, they are set to visible again, however mainting this is a nightmare, since my app is quiet big and I need to manage this for each element (button, lapel, panel, etc...) that cames covered by the menu when it is released.

Here is my jFrame structure:
[image: Here the main panel is the jPanel that will contain the other sub Jpanels that usser would access via the menu Settings panel is the common panel for all subpanels, it always shows the yellow strip at the top and the Buttons that shows up the menu]

Another issue that I noticed, it is that the menu pops up inmediatly when a button is pressed in some panel or if the user resizes the windows of the app. It just appears immediately without any animation.

So what am I doing wrong? How can accomplish fixxing this?
Thank you.

"After the edit:"
I incorporate here some code that will show the problem. Is a MRE version of the main problem.

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    
    
    public test() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  }

/////// THIS CODE IS GENERATED BY THE IDE/ / // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void initComponents() {  // You can skip this part, since this is the init of each component
        menu = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        goToA = new javax.swing.JButton();
        hideMenu = new javax.swing.JButton();
        goToA1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        interfaces = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        sttings = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        showMenu = new javax.swing.JButton();
        home = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panelA = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        cleares = new javax.swing.JButton();
        writes = new javax.swing.JButton();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 1206, 808));
        setLocation(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
        setMaximizedBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 1206, 808));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        setModalExclusionType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
        setName("Main"); // NOI18N
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        menu.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(38, 39, 40));
        menu.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        menu.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        menu.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        menu.setDebugGraphicsOptions(javax.swing.DebugGraphics.NONE_OPTION);
        menu.setDoubleBuffered(false);
        menu.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(293, 1808));
        menu.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 808));
        menu.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(295, 808));
        menu.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        menu.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
        goToA.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(38, 39, 40));
        goToA.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
        goToA.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        goToA.setText("GO TO A");
        goToA.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        goToA.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        goToA.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        goToA.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(235, 50));
        goToA.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(235, 50));
        goToA.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(235, 50));
        goToA.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                goToAMouseClicked(evt);            }        });
        goToA.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");             }   });
        hideMenu.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        hideMenu.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        hideMenu.setText("CLOSE THE MENU");
        hideMenu.setToolTipText("");
        hideMenu.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        hideMenu.setBorderPainted(false);
        hideMenu.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        hideMenu.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                hideMenuMouseClicked(evt);           }        });
        goToA1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(38, 39, 40));
        goToA1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
        goToA1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        goToA1.setText("GO TO HOME");
        goToA1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        goToA1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        goToA1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        goToA1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(235, 50));
        goToA1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(235, 50));
        goToA1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(235, 50));
        goToA1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {        });
        goToA1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                goToA1ActionPerformed(evt);            }        });
        javax.swing.GroupLayout menuLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(menu);
        menu.setLayout(menuLayout);
        menuLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            menuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(menuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(menuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(menuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addGroup(menuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(goToA1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(goToA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(menuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                        .addComponent(hideMenu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 148, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32))        );
        menuLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            menuLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(menuLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                .addComponent(goToA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 186, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(hideMenu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(159, 159, 159)
                .addComponent(goToA1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(225, 225, 225))        );
        interfaces.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        interfaces.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        interfaces.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        interfaces.setDebugGraphicsOptions(javax.swing.DebugGraphics.NONE_OPTION);
        interfaces.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        interfaces.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 808));
        interfaces.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        interfaces.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
        sttings.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        sttings.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        sttings.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        sttings.setDebugGraphicsOptions(javax.swing.DebugGraphics.NONE_OPTION);
        sttings.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 100));
        sttings.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        sttings.setOpaque(false);
        sttings.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(238, 206, 62));
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 26)); // NOI18N
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setText("   KEEP THIS TITLE ALWAYS ON TOP");
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(interfaces.getWidth(), 40));
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(interfaces.getWidth(), 40));
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setOpaque(true);
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(interfaces.getWidth(), 40));
        showMenu.setText("SHOW MENU");
        showMenu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                showMenuActionPerformed(evt);            }        });
        home.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        javax.swing.GroupLayout homeLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(home);
        home.setLayout(homeLayout);
        homeLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            homeLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1206, Short.MAX_VALUE)        );
        homeLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            homeLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 808, Short.MAX_VALUE)        );
        panelA.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        panelA.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        panelA.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        panelA.setDebugGraphicsOptions(javax.swing.DebugGraphics.NONE_OPTION);
        panelA.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        panelA.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        panelA.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1206, 808));
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        textArea.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        textArea.setRows(5);
        textArea.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(255, 212, 57)));
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        cleares.setText("WIPES THE TEXT BELOW");
        cleares.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                clearesActionPerformed(evt);            }        });
        writes.setText("WRITE A TEXT BELOW");
        writes.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                writesActionPerformed(evt);            }        });
        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelALayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelA);
        panelA.setLayout(panelALayout);
        panelALayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelALayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panelALayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(panelALayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(panelALayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(writes)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(cleares))
                    .addComponent(textArea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))        );
        panelALayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelALayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panelALayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(280, 280, 280)
                .addGroup(panelALayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(writes)
                    .addComponent(cleares))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(textArea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 416, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))        );
        javax.swing.GroupLayout sttingsLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(sttings);
        sttings.setLayout(sttingsLayout);
        sttingsLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, sttingsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(showMenu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1076, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panelA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(home, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        sttingsLayout.setVerticalGroup(            sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(sttingsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(showMenu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(728, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panelA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(sttingsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(home, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))        );
        interfaces.add(sttings, "card2");
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1206, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(menu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(0, 911, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(interfaces, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 808, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(menu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(interfaces, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))        );
        menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");        pack();    }
         /////////// END OF THE INIT OF THE COMPONENTS   /////// THIS CODE IS GENERATED BY THE IDE/ / // ///////////////
    /// HERE IS MY CODE:
    private void hideMenuMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        System.out.println("Closing Menu");
        if (menu.getWidth() > 0) {
            menu.setFocusable(true);
            Thread th = new Thread(){
                public void run () {
                    try {
                    for (double i = menu.getMaximumSize().width; i > -1; i=i-1.5) {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                        menu.setSize((int) i, menu.getHeight());   } /*LOOP END*/
                    } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);  }   }    };
            th.start();        }    }                                    
            
    private void goToAMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        panelA.setVisible(true);
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setText("   PANEL A");
        hideMenuMouseClicked(evt);
    }                                  

    private void showMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if (menu.getWidth() == 0) {
            menu.setSize(0, menu.getHeight());
            Thread th = new Thread(){
                public void run () {
                    try {for (double i = 0; i < menu.getMaximumSize().width + 1; i=i+1.5) {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                            menu.setSize((int) i, menu.getHeight());   } /*LOOP END*/
                    } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);    }   }     };
                    th.start();
                    menu.setSize(menu.getMaximumSize().width, menu.getHeight());
                    menu.setFocusable(true);    }    }                                        

    private void clearesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        textArea.setText("");    }                                       
        
    private void writesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        textArea.setText("PANEL A IS ONE OF THE DIFFERENT PANELS THAT THE APP WILL HAVE, AND THE USER WILL ACCESS TO THOSE VIA THE MENU");    }                                      
                            
    private void goToA1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        panelA.setVisible(false);
        home.setVisible(true);
        keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle.setText("You are now in home");    }   
    /////////////////// THIS IS THE MAIN CLASS ///////////// THIS CODE IS GENERATED BY THE IDE/ / // //////////////////
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;        }     }     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mreForStackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mreForStackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mreForStackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mreForStackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new mreForStackOverflow().setVisible(true);            }        });    }
    public javax.swing.JButton hideMenu;
    private javax.swing.JPanel interfaces;
    private javax.swing.JPanel sttings;
    private javax.swing.JButton cleares;
    private javax.swing.JButton goToA;
    private javax.swing.JButton goToA1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel home;
    private javax.swing.JLabel keepVisibleAlwaysThisTitle;
    private javax.swing.JPanel menu;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelA;
    private javax.swing.JButton showMenu;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
    private javax.swing.JButton writes;}
```

As far as I know, I am fairly sure you can just copy this code and compile it, and hopefully you may be able to reproduce the issue I am describing.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an  upper case character. We can't read your posted code because the forum highlights the variable names the same as class names.

Comment: * it is that the menu releases inmediatly* - I would guess the code execute too fast. All the repaint() requests are consolidated into a single repaint. A 1ms sleep is too small, try a larger value like 16 or 50. Experiment.

Comment: @camickr Thank for your anwser, hopefully I have fixed the variables, so I hope you guys can read the post with no issues. All variables are hopefully now lower case. About the 1ms sleep in the thread, let me explain: If the usser uses the button for Hiding/Showing the menu, it shows/hides smoothly and for me it looks fine. However if the usser has already pressed Hide menu, once he presses a button (not the button that releases the jMenu) or he resizes the windows, suddenly the menu just pops up there without any animation and without the user requesting it. The 1ms sleep looks fine for me.

Comment: 1) the variables have not changed in the posted code. Swing components have variable names as well, not just String variables. 2) Also, method names should NOT start with a capital letter. These a Java conventions used in any text book or tutorial you will find on the web. Learn by example and follow the standards.

Comment: Well, I tried, but the code doesn't compile. It uses classes and methods that aren't included. When you ask a question we are NOT interested in your application. We are only interested in the specific code that demonstrates the problem you are asking about. So this requires you so simplify the code to only the relevant code directly related to the stated problem. The code should be in a single class. We should then be able to copy/paste/compile and text the code to see the behaviour you describe.This is called an [mre]. For example none of the code related to the icons is required.

Comment: The point of an MRE is to simplify the problem. Many times while creating the MRE you will find the problem as it forces you to think strictly about the problem. In any case I have other stuff to do this afternoon. Maybe I'll check back later to see an a proper MRE has been posted.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for guiding me on how to make it clearer. I added the simple version of the problem. And I am proud (according to my tests) that you can run that code, and by iteracting with the interface you will notice the issues I have been describing above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, still not an MRE since:

1. the code doesn't even compile since the class name is incorrect. Class names should start with an upper case character. Why do I have to keep mentioning little details like this??? You get one free answer, but no more if you can't follow Java conventions when posting code!
2. there is still a lot of code not directly related to the problem. Your problem is about layering a menu over top of a button.

So all you need is:

1. All you need is a frame with the "Show Menu".
2. Then on the menu you need a "Hide Menu" button.

All the other components are not relevant to the problem you are describing.

I was able to resolve some issues but not everything.

> there is a jButton or a jLabel, these just overlay the content of the menu, they keep visible, and they came in front covering the menu's content.

Mouse events are passed to the component which has a MouseListener added to it. When the menu is visible and you move the mouse around the menu as the mouse moves over a button under the menu the button is painted because the button has a mouse listener added to it to handle the rollover effects of the button.

I was able to prevent this in most cases by adding a dummy MouseListener to the panel:

```
menu.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {});
menu.addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {});
```

However, it still causes a problem when you click on the "Show Menu" button and then move the mouse. Not sure why.

> the menu pops up inmediatly when a button is pressed in some panel or if the user resizes the windows

You logic only manipulates the setSize(...) method of the menu to hide/show it.

However when the frame is resized the layout manager is invoked which will reset the size() of the menu based on its preferred size and the menu is repainted.

The solution I used was to add:

```
menu.setVisible(false);
```

in the "Hide Menu" logic and add

```
menu.setVisible(true)
```

in the "Show Menu" logic.

I have never used a GroupLayout. I also don't use layout managers to display component in the 3rd dimension so I'm not sure if using the GroupLayout is the best solution for something like this.

Maybe instead the menu should be a `Glass Pane` of the frame that you can show/hide are required.

Or maybe you should be using a JLayeredPane.

Both of the above are better designed to show components in layers.

Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information. Specifically the sections on:

1. How to Use Root Panes
2. How to Use Layered Panes

Comment: Thank you for you patience. When I was creating the mre I had the feeling that it was overcharged, but I was not sure enough where to stop adding more code. All in all, I highly thank you.

Comment: *"..not sure enough where to stop adding more code"* The instant it can demonstrate the problem.